# Print out list (of list) from n files as n columns

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am trying to read lines from n files. Then I am going to print out all the data to ONE file. The tricky thing is that I don't know how many files thats the dir contains and I want to print it out nice so every file gets it own column. 
Example:(text is some data I don't care about, can use split to grab the [1])

```
File 1 contains:
text Line1
text Line2
text Line3
```

File 2 contains:

```
text Line01
text Line02
text Line03
```

I want to combine to one file like this:

```
File 1 File 2
Line1  Line01
Line2  Line02
Line3  Line03
```

One problem I have is that when I read the files, I read one file at a time and append each line to a list, but then how do I print it out the way I want.

```
fromfiles = ['Line1','Line2','Line3','Line01','Line02','Line03']
```

or

```
fromfiles2 = [['Line1','Line2','Line3'],['Line01','Line02','Line03']]
```

In case formfiles: How do I print out line1 and line01 at the same time, and then continue?

In case formfiles2: same problem as above really. I need to access multiple elements at the same time without knowing how many items in list, and then print out everything.

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Open both files at the same time and write out each line together?

Comment: So I should open n files at the same time? Doesn't sound good if you ask me.

Comment: @Kleazy: did you have a look at my answer? It's not a question of "sounding good". Just a question of requirement. Consider your input files are 1 GB each and you have 10 of them: You can still process them the way you want, but you **have to** process them line by line, because otherwise you would be running of RAM. However, I assume that your input files are not so large and an in-memory solution is entirely okay.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't read you question, thought you said 2 files.

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke: yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is made for this! Let's start from your `fromfiles2`:

```
>>> fromfiles2 = [['Line1','Line2','Line3'],['Line01','Line02','Line03']]
>>> outputlines = zip(*fromfiles2)
>>> for l in outputlines:
...     print "\t".join(l)
...
Line1   Line01
Line2   Line02
Line3   Line03
```

This is how `zip` works basically:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Of course this also works with more than two arguments :-).

This is a good approach when your files are small. Then, you can safely read them into memory first, merge the data in memory, and then write the merged data to the output file. However, if your input is really large (GB of data), then you should read the input files line by line simultaneously, build an output line, write it to file and only then proceed with the next line in the input files.

If you got the concept of `zip`, then you can look into `itertools.izip` for making things more memory-efficient:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> for l in izip(*fromfiles2):
...     print "\t".join(l)
...
Line1   Line01
Line2   Line02
Line3   Line03
```

Also, if your files do not have the same number of input files, you might want to have a look at [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> fromfiles3 = [['Line1','Line2','Line3'],['Line01','Line02']]
>>> for l in izip_longest(*fromfiles3, fillvalue="Nothing"):
...     print "\t".join(l)
...
Line1   Line01
Line2   Line02
Line3   Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I used fromfiles2 and zip, then I just had to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you read each of the files, keep find the max number of lines (probably using len()) you encountered in a file.

Use the second solution, and iterate through each row number 1 to the global max. If a line entry exists for that file, print it; otherwise, skip it.

```
# loop through files
# max = number of lines max

for i in range(max):
  line = []
  for file in fromfiles2:
    if len(file) > i:
      line.append(file[i])
    else:
      line.append('')
  # print your line here
```

Answer (score -3):

Save it like in fromfiles2 ... a List of Lists.

then check the maximum number of lines (the largest .count() of all lists).

then make a for-loop from 0 to `<<maximum number of lines -1>>` like this (Pseudo Code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < maxNumOfLines; i++) {
  String lineToPrint = "";
  for(int j = 0; j < numberOfLists; j++) {
    lineToPrint += listOfLists[j][i];
  }
  File.Write(lineToPrint);
}
```

N.B.: You have to check if the index [j][i] exists, as the files will not be of the same length.

Comment: pah screw it ... i think one can get what i meant with my less than python pseudoish code.

Comment: The poster asked for python, as the tag implies. Please no more of your pseudo code.